# meaning of the pbrase "as to be" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the context:

> And then there is the argument that using such a destructive weapon was morally reprehensible because it was so destructive **as to be** qualitatively different from other weapons.

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/Objoad6rG6U). It is at 10 minute and 40 second.
I cannot see how *as to be* fits there, and because of it I cannot understand what the host means by the sentence. Does he mean it was so destructive because it was qualitatively different?

Comment: **As to be** = **that it was**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

> The ladder was so rickety as to be unsafe.

The pattern `{noun} BE so {adjective-phrase1} as to be {adjective-phrase2}` is used to present a situation where {noun}'s  degree of {adjective1} meets or exceeds the threshold necessary for {adjective2} to be predicated of it.

> The bread was so stale as to be inedible.
>
> The coffee was so bitter as to be undrinkable.
>
> The venture was so risky as to be untenable.

You can also substitute a noun-phrase for adjective-phrase2:

> He was so drunk as to be a deadly risk behind the steering wheel.

Comment: Can I substitute the word "as" with "that" there. For example: "The ladder was so rickety that it was unsafe." Does this sentence sound more natural than your example?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Both are idiomatic. The *that*-clause version is conversational; the **as to be** version tends to be used outside of conversational contexts, at least in AmE.